# \newcommand - Dynamically run command created with parameters

Tags: macros

The problem is self-explanatory:

`\newcommand{family}[1][sf]{\#1family}`

This does not work, but how can I make it work?

Comment: `\newcommand{\family}[1][sf]{\csname #1family\endcsname}`?

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much.

Comment: @JairoA.delRio If you would like you can post a formal answer I will accept it.